# Is this past progressive sentence?

Tags: past-tense, past-continuous

Are the following sentences actually in past progressive?

- She was sleeping on the couch.
- The dog was barking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the sentences are the examples of ***past progressive***.

The past progressive tense is used to talk about continuing action. It talks about something that was going on or happening at that time in the past.

The past progressive tense is formed using *"to be"* verb in the past tense along with the present participle of the verb ending with *-ing*

> She was sleeping on the couch.

Check out - *was* + *sleep* + *-ing*